# Encoding::UndefinedConversionError with activerecord-sqlserver-adapter

Tags: sql-server, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm having problems when connecting to a legacy database in SQL Server. The problem happens when read a string with special characters and try to insert it into another database (sqlite in development), which throws me the following error:

```
Encoding::UndefinedConversionError: "\xC3" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8
```

The database has a latin1-like collation. I have set `client charset = UTF-8` in my freetds.conf file, and I have `encoding: utf8` in my database.yml file.

It actually seems the freetds driver is making the right conversion, but for some reason the ruby library is not aware about it, because the problematic string is `ESPA\xC3\x91A`, which is actually the right binary representation for `ESPAÑA`, so calling `force_encoding('UTF-8')` on the string makes the error dissapear.

As an additional note, when I assign the string to the other model it gives me the following message:

```
Binary data inserted for `string` type on column `email`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/tiny_tds solved this and other problems I was having with the ODBC driver.